# Using dynamic data source name in Lookup Transformation inside Azure Data Flows

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Inside my data pipeline, I am trying to merge two datasets, a data from SQL table and a corresponding json file in Azure Blob Storage. 
Each row in SQL data contains a name of blob file, what I am trying to achieve is, for each row get the file mentioned in of the columns, join that json blob data with row and write to another blob.

First i tried using `Lookup` and `ForEach` activities inside `Data Pipelines`, parameterised blob data set to read the name based on value in column but then I didn't find any way to write each data along with blob data, it did copied the blob file though.

Then I tried using `Lookup Transformation` inside `Data Flows`, but i failed to use column value as the name of a second source to merge data from.

Is there anyway inside data pipeline or data flows to merge two datasets where the name of one of the dataset is dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in Data Flows. The dataset, filenames, tables, and columns can all be parameterized.

Comment: Do you have link to any resource? I tried finding some without any success. I know how to use parameters, the problem I am facing is, loading file from storage against each row and merge with that row.

Comment: Did you look at the "Column to store file name" property on the Source tranform? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#mapping-data-flow-properties